# \hbox_set:Nn ⟨hbox⟩ {⟨contents⟩} typesets but doesn't print the ⟨contents⟩

Tags: boxes, expl3

In the `interface3.pdf` documentation, it is said:

> `\hbox:n {⟨contents⟩}` Typesets the `⟨contents⟩` into a horizontal box of
> natural width and then includes this box in the current list for
> typesetting.
>
> `\hbox_set:Nn ⟨hbox⟩ {⟨contents⟩}` Typesets the `⟨contents⟩` at natural
> width and then stores the result inside the `⟨hbox⟩`.

I wonder what is the meaning here of "Typesets the `⟨contents⟩`", since the latter doesn't print anything, unlike the former which, admittedly, is said to "include th[e] box in the current list for typesetting".

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\hbox:n { Foo }
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { Bar }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `expl3` but that sounds like the normal TeX way of doing `\setbox0=\hbox{...}`. The content of `\hbox` is typeset in the sense that everything is expanded and executed, and the resulting `\box` with register number `0` really contains the typeset content, not some code which will be typeset when you write `\box0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the docs says, it typesets the material, *i.e.* turns it from a series of input tokens into a list of glyphs, etc., which can be printed. However, `\hbox_set:Nn` does *not* add anything to the current list (in contrast to `\hbox:n`), which means that typeset material is simply stored (under the name of the `N`-type variable).